# Conditionally add a click function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to conditionally add a 'click' function in d3. My section of code looks like this

```
.on("click", function(d,i){
            if ((d.i)<(crumbtrail.length)){
              transition
            }
});
```

What am I doing wring?

thanks

Comment: what is  transition?

Comment: its a function called transition

Comment: I don't think `d` and `i` are going to be what you are expecting them to be, and if they were, you'd probably want to use `d[i]` instead of `d.i`

Comment: `d` is data, `i` is index... I'm not sure d.i makes sense... probably d[i], or just i. Also, should there be parenthesis after `transition`?

Comment: defeinatly no parenthesis, already tried this. But thanks